# Snowflake ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when trying to connect using externalbrowser on Python

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to Snowflake using **'authenticator': 'externalbrowser'** from a Python script. This was working perfectly until today. Now I keep getting an "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error.
Here's what happens:

1. I run the script, it opens a browser window and asks me to log in
   with my organization credentials.
2. Login is correct. I get a
   message saying: "Redirecting to Snowflake client in 1 seconds.."
3. After a couple of seconds, I get a chrome error screen with a
   "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error.

As I said, this was working fine until today. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: If you open the browser manually, use the exactly same URL as the code uses and log in, does it work?

Comment: I don't suppose there have been any recent networking changes?  Maybe try accessing outside of your Python code?

Comment: Usually **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** is a client side error. You could try clearing the browser cache and see if that helps. You should also use browser Developer tools at Network tab and see if the request is sent out and if an error is returned.

Comment: It was my browser cache! I cleared it, and everything is working fine again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a browser cache issue. Cleaning it solved the issue.